# Can't generate igraph_degree_sequence_game on igraph

Tags: c++, c, igraph

I want to use the igraph_degree_sequence_game igraph graph generator to generate a network. The example on the igraph C library works well on my computer, but if I change to some other simple degree distributions (see the code below), I got this error:

```
Error at games.c:830 :degree sequence game (simple), Out of memory.
```

I expect this gives me an undirected network with 4 nodes and each of it has 3 neighbors. I don't know where did I do wrong. Thank you for your kind help and response.

```
#include <igraph.h>

int main() {
  igraph_t g;
  igraph_vector_t outdeg, indeg, vec;
  igraph_bool_t is_simple;

  igraph_vector_init_real(&outdeg, 4,3,3,3,3);
  igraph_vector_init(&vec, 0);

  /* checking the simple method, undirected graphs */
  igraph_degree_sequence_game(&g, &outdeg, 0, IGRAPH_DEGSEQ_SIMPLE);
  if (igraph_is_directed(&g) || igraph_vcount(&g) != 4)
  return 1;
  if (igraph_degree(&g, &vec, igraph_vss_all(), IGRAPH_OUT, 1))
  return 2;
  igraph_vector_print(&vec);
  igraph_destroy(&g);


  igraph_vector_destroy(&vec);
  igraph_vector_destroy(&outdeg);
  igraph_vector_destroy(&indeg);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the example should be updated, because `igraph_vector_init_real` is not part of the public API. Anyway, the problem is, that (as the name suggests), this function expects real (i.e. double) literals. I.e. the correct way to use it is

```
igraph_vector_init_real(&outdeg, 4, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0);
```

Btw. another error in your code is calling `igraph_vector_destroy` on `indeg`, which was never initialized. This might or might not generate a runtime error.